# Add a button for opening chats easily? Maybe improve the total chat system!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

#### The problem:

Say you have a chat about a problem but you have to go offline for the night or something and you want to continue later. I find it really hard to find the chat again and I probably will open a new chat with the same user, even though that is very difficult (I usually go back to the question from which I started the chat).

#### Why a better chat system:

I think the chat system has potential and I think it would be used more by users if there was an easy way to access it. I think people feel more comfortable when they can just explain their question to one or more people that are online instead of having to wait until somebody answers the question on StackOverflow and having to fear for reputation loss (I guess that more experienced users of SO will still ask questions the 'normal' way).

#### Some features that may be nifty:

1. A button next to the notifications and reputation change buttons we have now; this button can open a list of users that you have recently chatted with and give you access to the chat so you can continue chatting.
2. An invite button to invite users to a chat/chatroom, or to start a chat with this user. When you invite someone to a chat between two users, the chat can turn into a chatroom or a private group that you can invite people to (like the Facebook chat).
3. A few badges related to chatting: `first chat` or `first chatroom`, which obviously correspond to creating a chat with another user and creating a chatroom for people to chat in.

#### Downsides:

Now we need to ask ourselves: *"would improving the chat system also improve the whole site, or would it discourage asking a question on StackOverflow and encourage using chat instead?"*

I don't think that there will be fewer questions, because people stick to a certain pattern. When you are used to doing something one way, it will be very hard for you to change to another way. That means that if you are used to asking questions you will probably not switch to a chat.

Comment: if you downvote this you might also want to show your opinion. I think it would be a good idea but if you think I am wrong you should tell me why!

Comment: "An invite button to invite users to a chat/chatroom".... absolutely not.  You fail to recognize that some users would be invited to chats dozens or hundreds of times per day.  Stack Overflow is not a social network.  The chat system is a nice side-part to the overall system, but it really needs to remain separate from the Q&A part of the network.  And there are badges for chatting already, but not many.  I don't see the benefit of adding more.

Comment: well than they should add a way to turn on or off if you want tobe invided or not

Comment: Given that your problem simply is "I can't find the old chat", how about simply using bookmarks or pinned tabs; or just learning how to properly search your browser history?

Comment: I have like 300 bookmarks. also if you read the whole question you can see that that is not the full problem. I also dont like the system as it is now

Comment: Well, your proposed alternative of chat as a way for noobs to ask their questions (at least this is what I can grok from that) will never happen because it goes against the whole "knowledge repository" idea - we explicitly have the Q/A format as it's searchable and distractionless and has a ton of other advantages over a chatroom. Also, there already are tons of other sites for that. And re 300 bookmarks, so what? Make a bookmark folder "SO user chats" and put them in there; as the title for a discussion between two users includes their full names you can even search that folder for usernames.

Comment: well that's an idea but I am just trying to inprove the site, I think many people would use it

Comment: @CoderGuy l4mpi's point is that we **don't want** many people to use chat to ask questions; it is at odds with the core purpose of the SE system. Easier access to your recent chats, on the other hand, seems like a reasonable feature, although easily achieved with bookmarks (you can also use favourites, as there's a tab for that: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=favorite&sort=active).

Answer (score 3):

There is already an easily accessible way to go to SO's Chat:

[image]

There, you can see an overview of your recent rooms, on the "Mine" tab:

[image]

As far as I know, this overview also includes "personal" chatrooms.

Now, being able to invite random people to chatrooms can be *extremely* problematic. The more well-known users of SO would be spammed to death with those invites.
Not to mention something like that giving spammers a very convenient function to target individual people, which is less public, and as such, less likely to get them banned in a timely fashion.

Comment: still a button on the hot bar would be cooler

Comment: It would be redundant, as there already is a button available, in a dropdown, on the menu bar.

Comment: but inviting people would not be a bad idea... you can turn of the invites with an option against spam or set a limit like 10 invites can be send to each person and when he starts or cancels a chat you invite him back. also i think it would be used very much

Comment: Even if someone can only be invited 10 times, you'd still get spammed with chat invites. As soon as our "celebrity users would decline those 10, they'd get 10 more. _And_ you'd be unable to get your own invite in, between all the spam.

Comment: Than you turn off invites and invite the guy you want to be invited by!!

Comment: Where is that dropdown menu now that the header was changed?